# Safest Way to Reduce Size of Large Images

Tags: c#, image-processing

I spent quite a lot of time here and on other sites trying to find a good way to resample images.  The code below is the one that I am using

```
public static Bitmap ResampleImage(Image img, Size size, long quality) {
        try {
            var bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, size));
            }

            return setImageQualityLevel(bmp, quality);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.Warn(string.Format("Image Resample Failed:\r\n{0}\r\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                return (Bitmap)img;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately it regularly fails triggering the catch block.  Mostly this is with big images (up to 20Mb) - These sizes are of no benefit in my application but I would rather not say to my users - cut it down to 1Mb before trying to use it.  I also get OOM failures on  loading the image using something like this:

```
image2Use = new Bitmap(image.Filename);
```

It is therefore failing even before I can get it into my resample code.

So what I am really looking for is some safe way to get an image in and re-size it.  I would rather not go to the overhead of using a third party library since this is all I want to do - load a big image file and make it a lot smaller!

Comment: Too bad you didn't include the exception message.  That information could be useful to someone trying to help.

Comment: You've been posting this question for a while now.  A true scruffy duck would call img.Dispose() in that method.  Of course that's not the right thing to do, you'd assume the caller take care of that.  Also pretty sure that people that design airports can afford a 64-bit operation system.

Comment: @Steve - I have seen three exceptions reported:  OOM; Generic GDI+; and Invalid Parameter

Comment: @Hans  Thanks.  I am certainly very scruffy when it comes to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please considered using a third-party.

[ImageMagick has a C# interface](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php)

They have a nice `convert` command-line utility that will do exactly what you want.

I've used them for several years now and have been very impressed with the ease of use and capabilities of their libraries in different environments (Windows Desktop all the way to *nix servers).

Comment: As per my question I have considered using them but would rather not go to the overhead of using one if I can avoid it.  I would hope that there is a managed way to do this in C#

Comment: Understood, but consider doing a test first to determine if using a third-party tool would 1) solve your memory problem, 2) give accurate results, and 3) quick to develop.  Sometimes its easier and faster not to "roll your own".  Metrics would answer if the overhead is worth it, but as hardware is getting cheaper and processing power more impressive I've found from a business perspective, sometimes throwing hardware at an inefficient algorithm/solution, is better and faster.  Best of luck.

Comment: I have to agree with you.  While trying to avoid using a third party library it is clear to me that the managed code is just not able to cope so I am now investigating ImageMagick and some other libraries

Answer (score 0):

Since it only happens on large images...
And assuming your process starts immediately after the image uploads...

It's possible the image hasn't finished copying before your process starts to work on it.

To verify, hand copy one of the large images.  Then, start your process on it.  If it works, you'll know your process is OK.

Comment: Steve Thanks.  I am now reasonably sure that the problem is related to the size of image when it gets into memory.  For example a 16Mb image on disk ends up at over 300Mb when in memory.  I think GDI+ runs out of memory at some point.